# first data global gateway api gives unpredictable information

Tags: c#, .net, firstdata

I have created a test accout on first data global gate wayand used their api in my webapplication (C# and .net). but there is a problem that it shows unpredictable behaviour. sometimes it accepted wrong credit card numbers but sometime if I give correct credit card number then it  gives `transcation declined due to invalid credit card`.I tried eyerything but there is no effect.please help me.
I am using `1909460160.pem` file,'Linkpointtransaction.dll' and lpssl.dll.It works fine sometime but sometime it gives error weather I passed correct or incorrect value.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what have you tried?

Comment: honestly , I've worked with first data global, cybersource, worldpay, and authorize. I had similar problems when dealing with first data. Authorize is the best in terms of API and documentation.

Comment: Authorize is the best in terms of API and documentation means pls clear it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried their web API instead of the .NET API? The web API uses SOAP requests and was a bit easier to integrate in once I got everything setup that is. As far as unpredictable results, I haven't experienced that problem on either API.